There is not window.Telegram.WebApp.stories in Telegram API
I am trying to use Telegram API to create Stories by clicking on button in my Mini App(written on Next.js) in Telegram Bot. As I found I can use method stories.sendStory, but I do not have stories object.
Also, I have Premium account in Telegram, but I do not think it could depend on object in code.
Code:
  const handleSendStory = () => {
    if (window.Telegram.WebApp && window.Telegram.WebApp.stories) {
      const { WebApp } = window.Telegram;

      WebApp.expand();

      WebApp.stories
        .sendStory({
          media: [
            {
              type: 'photo', // или 'video'
              media: imageUrl,
            },
          ],
          text: 'Check out this awesome story!',
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Story sent successfully!');
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
          console.error('Error sending story:', error);
        });
    } else {
      console.error('Telegram WebApp stories API is not available.');
    }
  };

So, I have a lot of functions and method in window.Telegram.WebApp, but I do not have Stories object with methods.
What am I doing wrong?
Do we have library for Telegram that can help with making Stories in Telegram with my Next.js app?
